# Java collection GC

Tags: java, collections, methods

If I created inside method some kind of collection - list, array or map, after exiting from method if this collection contains references also for external objects GC free the memory? 
Or it will be memory leak?
Thanks.

Comment: In Java, its almost impossible to create a C style memory leak.  So much so that when the term is used in Java it means any undesirable increase in memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there will be no leak. Once your code has no references to a given object, the object becomes eligible for garbage collection.

It does not matter whether the object itself (e.g. a collection) contains references to live objects -- it's references *in the opposite direction* that matter.